# How to change status from online to offline when user disconnects from internet in firestore?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I want to build functionality similar to WhatsApp online/offline status.
I am not able to figure out how we can build this, when the user gets disconnected from internet how we can update the document when the user is offline (not connected to internet ) ?.

I am using front end as reactJs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is known as a presence system. No such system is natively built into Cloud Firestore, as the protocol it uses to communicate with the server is connectionless. But there's a solution that uses the Firebase Realtime Database to store presence information in Firestore too, which is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

If you're only just getting started with the app, it might be easier to skip Firestore for the moment and use the presence system that Realtime Database has directly. To get started with that, have a look at the documentation on [managing presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-presence) and the examples of a  [full presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample).