# Change The status of user to offline in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have Taxi App, And I need add when the driver closed the app, the status of the driver changed to offline in firestore

how I can do that?
plz explain  for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore has no built-in capability to write something in the database after the client has disconnected.There's a solution but  that uses the Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Functions to store presence information in Firestore too, which is documented here [Build presence in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).Found this [blog](https://blog.campvanilla.com/firebase-firestore-guide-how-to-user-presence-online-offline-basics-66dc27f67802) you can also check this  which might help.

> Depending on the type of app you're building, you might find it useful
> to detect which of your users or devices are actively online —
> otherwise known as detecting "presence."
>
> Cloud Firestore doesn't natively support presence, but you can
> leverage other Firebase products to build a presence system.

You can refer this stackoverflow [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71051274/add-online-offline-status-in-flutter-app-like-whatsapp-using-firebase-but-how-i) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70330860/how-to-change-status-from-online-to-offline-when-user-disconnects-from-internet)